# Testing hasOwnProperty() on resolved promise object with chai-as-promised

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to run the following tests:

```
describe('set()', function () {
    var returnedUser = session.set(user);

    it('should return a User object', function () {
        //this works fine
        return returnedUser.should.eventually.equal(user);
    });

    it('returned User object should have sessionId appended', function() {
        //DOES NOT WORK; always passes
        return returnedUser.should.eventually.hasOwnProperty('thisdoesnotexist');
    });
});
```

I'm trying to figure out the right syntax to test whether the returned `User` object contains a `'sessionId'` property. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out by looking a little more closely at the chaijs [docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/).

```
it('returned User object should have sessionId appended', function() {
    return returnedUser.should.eventually.include.keys('sessionId');
});
```